# PHP file uploader (images) Not uploading certain images

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

Trying to upload certain images with PHP but it won't work 
I have used the example from [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) to try and upload an image with a higher value for hight then width.

It's working fine on "normal" images (horizontal), but as I said I'm not getting it to work on vertical aligned images.

The script does not recognise the file at all I think.

The errormessage is : Undefined index on the line where this goes $_FILES["file"]["name"])

****THIS SCRIPT IS JUST FOR CHECKING THE FILE I KNOW IT DOESENT UPLOAD IT****

here is the image im trying to get PHP to check http://rubenringdal.net/img/testigjen.jpg

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

    <?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: edited, sorry for the bad spelling

Comment: Your script isn't complete. Keep reading the page at W3Schools, you'll find the section on "Restrictions on Upload" and "Saving the Uploaded File".  Finish the script and then see if it works.

Comment: where is the code to save the uploaded file?

Comment: What do you mean by "Horizontal" or "Vertical"? In your script you are not checking or getting any height or width. Do you know what's your max file size to upload?

Comment: I know im not uploading it with that code snippet, but i get an error just trying to get PHP to read the file.

Comment: "but i get an error just trying to get PHP to read the file" And what's the error? That's kind of an important detail for debugging.

Comment: Undefined index is the error.

Comment: Please give the _exact_ and _entire_ error message as it is displayed, not your interpretation of it. Help us help you.

Comment: What is the size of your vertical aligned image?  Most web servers have a limitation on the file upload size, usually defined in php.ini. Perhaps you're hitting the limit with your vertical image but your horizontal image is below the limit.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: file in "filepath" on line 3. On line 3 is this: $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: BTW, file uploaders don't care about the orientation of the image.

Comment: thx Robbert. that might actually be the case. Just thought the script would read the file even if the img was to big. Will come back with answer :)

Comment: Thx again Robbert! Looks like that was it. Just confusing when it didnt read the file at all. Put your comment as an answer plz! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is large than what you are allowing, 20 kb, it will not work so change this  to a greater value.

```
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < **20000**)
```

And you have to check if anything has been uploaded before you process it.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES["file"]))//Check if its not empty
{


     $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```